# javascript to get previous url of visitor from contact form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to track my prospects from which URL(like fb, g+ or mailer) they have visited my website.This is all is for understanding visitor for better digital marketing.

My Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dSp4g/

Please help me with code as below

***Thanks in advance***

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputEmail">Full name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control " id="exampleInputName" placeholder="Enter your full name" style="color:#000 !important;">
 </div>

<div class="form-group">
<input type="hidden" class="form-control " id="sourcecode">
</div>                                          

<div class="form-group last">
<button class="mailbtn">Submit</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.mailbtn').live('click',function(){

            name = $('#exampleInputName').val();

            sc = $('#sourcecode').val();

            $(document).ready(function() { 
                if (sourcecode = $.parsequery().s) 
                    {
                        $("#source").val(sourcecode); }
             });


            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async : false,
            url: "mail.php",
                data: { name:name, sourcecode:sc}
            })

            .done(function( msg ) {
            $('.mail_middle').html('');
            $('.mail_middle').html('We will call you to confirm your delivery address.Thank you.');
            return false;

            });



    });
```

**mail.php**

```
<?php
$to =  array("my_email1","my_email2");
$message .= "<table border='1'>";
$message .= "<tr><td>Name    </td><td>".$_POST['name']."</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td>Source   </td><td>".$_POST['sc']."</td></tr>";
$message .= "</table>";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 

$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"; 

$headers .=  'from: '.$from .'' . "\r\n" .

            'Reply-To: '.$from.'' . "\r\n" .

            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
foreach($to as $row)
{
   mail($row,$subject,$message,$headers);
}

echo "Mail Sent.";
die;
?>
```

Comment: My friend, after using this code, I am able to process my form.Insort form is not submitting...

Answer (score 1):

Change `$_POST['sc']`

```
$message .= "<tr><td>Source   </td><td>".$_POST['sc']."</td></tr>";
```

to `$_POST['sourcecode']`

```
$message .= "<tr><td>Source   </td><td>".$_POST['sourcecode']."</td></tr>";
```

as `sourcecode` is the name (where`sc` is the value)

```
data: { name:name, sourcecode:sc}
```

Comment: ya i have changed as per your mention, but even though i am not able to submit mu form, its processing & processing...

Comment: I took a look at your jsFiddle. Looking at this line -> `if (sourcecode = $.parsequery().s)`. 2 thoughts - (1) It should probably be `==` not `=` -> `if (sourcecode == $.parsequery().s)` and (2) where is `$.parsequery().s` defined as that is not a standard function in jQuery. Also [`.live()`](https://api.jquery.com/live/) was deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9. Would recommend changing to `$('.mailbtn').on('click',function(){` or `$('.mailbtn').click(function(){`. Last thing - why do you have `$(document).ready(function() {` inside your function?

Comment: Thanks Sean for make me understandable, but I am not good javascript modifier, I don't know how to make changes in javascript, So can you plz help me with FIDDLE updated by you....

Answer (score 0):

HTML

add a

`<input type="hidden" name="the_ref" value="<?= $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>">`

JS

modify to

`data: { name:name, sourcecode:sc, the_ref:ref}`

PHP

add a

`$message .= "<tr><td>Visitor came from </td><td>".$_POST['the_ref']."</td></tr>";`

your jquery implementation fails because in your php you are trying to read the `$_POST['sc']` instead of `$_POST['sourcecode']`

Comment: actually Now i am not able to submit my form...can help me with my fiddle??? should i remove $(document).ready(function() { 
                if (sourcecode = $.parsequery().s) 
                    {
                        $("#source").val(sourcecode); }
             });